# How to change the timestamp of a bus service in Azure?

Tags: azure, servicebus

I used this tutorial: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2011/12/cross-devicecross-location-pub-sub-part-2-using-windows-azure-service-bus-topics-subscriptions-in-windows-phone-71.html

But I can not find a way to change the timestamp messages.
(I would limit it to 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

For "timestamp", I am assuming you mean define the lifetime of messages? Service Bus allows you to set the TimeToLive property on a messages and after that duration expires these messages will expire and hence not be delivered. A WindowsPhone SDK can be downloaded from [here](http://servicebus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9715#213975), and you can set the [BrokeredMessage.TimeToLive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.timetolive.aspx) property on every messages as appropriate.